# How to convert font size (in px) to the unit used in the document (mm) for svg

Tags: svg, font-size

I have svg created in inkscape [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/00ed092d8a66a7d71ba006575ac82228).

The document size is in `mm`. For the 2 text fields, the font size is given like this:

```
style="...;font-size:31.420084px;..."
```

So it is given in `px`. Now I want the size of the font related to the document size.

But how should I convert the font-size in `px` to `mm`? I would need something like `dpi`, but the document does not specify anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, your viewBox matches your document dimensions:

```
width="164.28572mm"
height="78.10714mm"
viewBox="0 0 164.28572 78.10714"
```

that means all unit less values are in mm. Just specify your font-size without units (**or in your case when you use css just keep your document untouched and use px**).

The confusing part is, that px in svg are always user units and not device pixels, for that reason, your font-size is already given in mm... so `font-size:31.420084px` in your document is equal to `font-size:31.420084mm` in a viewBox less document (where user units equal to device pixels)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" width="100mm" height="20mm">
  <text x="0" y="12" font-size="12px">12px</text>
</svg>
<svg >
  <text x="0" y="12mm" font-size="12mm">12mm</text>
</svg>
```

Thats where it gets confusing. In the next example "1mm" is equal to 3.6 user units, but because 1 user unit equals 1mm in the real world, one svg mm equals 3.6 real mm ...

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50mm" height="50mm">
  <text x="0" y="5" font-size="1mm">font-size: 1mm</text>
  <text x="0" y="10" font-size="3.6">font-size: 3.6</text>
</svg>
```

[Units](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units) in SVG are a bit wired, but well defined...

The [SVGLength Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/SVGLength) has a Method `convertToSpecifiedUnits`.
you can use that to convert between different units in SVG.

```js
var l = svg.createSVGLength()
l.newValueSpecifiedUnits(SVGLength.SVG_LENGTHTYPE_PX, 12)
l.convertToSpecifiedUnits(SVGLength.SVG_LENGTHTYPE_MM)

out1.innerHTML = l.valueAsString
```

```css
svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg">
</svg>
12px = <span id="out1"></span>
```

Comment: `newValueSpecifiedUnits` _then_ `convertToSpecifiedUnits` ‍♀️ ... finally I get it. ‍♀️

Answer (score 3):

The standard DPI used in an SVG document is the standard DPI that is specified by the CSS standard.  That is 96dpi, or 96 standard CSS pixels per inch.

There are 25.4 mm per inch.  So to convert `px` to `mm`, the formula will be:

```
mm = 25.4 * (px / 96)
```

So if we plug your original `31.420084px` into that formula, the result is `8.31mm`.

Note that CSS doesn't take into account the real word DPI of the device that you are rendering to. It uses that fixed approximation of 96pixels per inch. So you can't rely on the fact that an element with size `96px` or `25.4mm` will actually be that size on screen, or when printed.